# How to edit or modify Kaa sandbox demo app

Tags: kaa

I am thinking of doing further work on kaa projects but i have few questions. I actually want to modify the source code of the GPIO control esp and GPIO control android. Is this posible? I mean downloading the demo source code fromm Kaa sandbox and editing them.

```
         What IDE do i use for the GPIO control esp and GPIO control android? How do i compile them. How do i run them again on my android phone and on ESP8266 device?
         I will appreciate a guide to doing this or a better way  of doing this.
```

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

You can download code of Kaa Sample Applications from Kaa Sandbox (or GitHub), but changing the code embedded on Kaa Sandbox is not trivial and long procedure.

Should you want to contribute your code changes, you may open a pull request on GitHub's Kaa Sample Applications repository.

Regarding your question about IDE. Kaa project does not limit or recommend using (or not using) of any IDE. That means you can use any one suitable for you. Also, you would normally use different IDE of Android and ESP8266. You should check the appropriate platforms recommendations and documentation on how to develop, debug and program the respective devices.